# Java Generics wildcard extends final class

Tags: java, generics

Why does Java doesn't throw any warning when compiling my `TestGenerics` `class`, considering that the `String` `class` is `final` and cannot be extended?

```
import java.util.*;
    public class TestGenerics { 
        public void addStrings(List<? extends String> list) {
          // some code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: @L4zy When I tried to use the method I got a warning...Also go this while compiling `Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type:`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's say I had a method like this:

```
public List<? extends T> filterOutNulls(List<T> input) { ...
```

Granted, not the best signature in the world, but still perfectly legal. What would happen if I passed a `List<String>` to that method? According to the signature, it returns a `List<? extends String>`. If Java disallowed that type, it'd be impossible to use this method for `List<String>` (or at least, it'd be impossible to use the return value).

Secondarily, the `extends` syntax is still useful in this case, since `List<String>` and `List<? extends String>` have different restrictions -- specifically, you can't add anything but a `null` literal to `List<? extends String>`. I'll sometimes use `? extends` to signify that a collection is read-only (since the only `T`s you can pass in are `null`), and `? super` to signify write-only (since you can only get out `T`s as `Object`). This isn't completely fool-proof (you can still call remove methods, pass in `null`s, downcast, etc) but serves as a gentle reminder of how the collection is probably meant to be used.

Comment: There are maybe use cases to return bounded wildcard lists like this but I would usually avoid it. Objects returned by some method leave the encapsulated area of their class and should be seen as owned by the place that called the method. If you want to give restricted access to some internal list return `Collections.unmodifiableList()` / have a method like `YourObject.addToInternalList(SomeData)`. That enforces correct usage and you can [Keep bounded wildcards out of return values](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07018/#4.0).

Comment: @zapl Matter of style, I suppose. If you return a `Collections.unmodifiableList`, there's nothing to indicate that in the type signature. So now I might thing I got a copy of the list, and then I'll get an `UnsupportedOperationException` when I try to modify it -- it trades verbosity of a reference type (at the call site) for type safety. It'd be nice if the JDK had a superinterface of each collection class that only had read methods, but it doesn't; basically, I (sometimes) use `List<? extends String>` as a poor man's `ReadList<String>`, since the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: Not visible at compile time is indeed problematic, you have to rely on users reading your documentation. [`Iterable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) could be an option although that supports removal. Or something like Guava's [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html) which has it at least in the name but since it is a `List` has `.add()` etc as well.

Comment: If I wanted to replace type checking with loosey-goosey documentation, I'd use Python. ;)

Answer (score 7):

The compiler doesn't really take note of that fact, because it doesn't matter. `String`s are still allowed in the list, and in the final product, the possibility of anything extending `String` is not found. After [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), it comes out like this:

```
public void addStrings(List list)
```

As you can see, there is now no suggestions of a class extending `String`. If you do create a class extending `String`, that will be itself a compile error. There's no need for javac to worry about that.

Comment: By that reasoning, you should be able to pass a `List<Apple>` to a method that expects a `List<Orange>`, since after erasure they're both just `List`. It's certainly true of the bytecode, but the whole point of generics is to provide type safety *above and beyond* what byte code can provide.

Comment: No, erasure does not remove any type information from method signatures. In bytecode, the method will have a *generic signature* of "<:+Ljava/lang/String;>(Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;)V" (or something like this).

Comment: @Rogério I'll need to check on that

Answer (score 0):

The type system does not consider `List<String>` and `List<? extends String>` equivalent, even though at the time of compiling, `String` has no subtypes other than itself, therefore any object that is a `List<? extends String>` must also be a `List<String>`.

One explanation is that `final` is not final - it's ok to remove `final` from a class and nothing should break: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.2

It's not without precedence that the type system takes `final` into consideration; for example, we cannot cast a `String` to a `Runnable`, because the compiler figures that if an object is `String`, it cannot be some unknown subclass that implements `Runnable`.

If we want generics also to make reasoning like that and deduce that `List<String>` and `List<? extends String>` are equivalent, it'll make typing rules even more complicated.