# Wildcard extending final Optional class

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, option-type, final

The [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) class is declared as final in Java. Nevertheless, it contains two methods, `flatMap` and `or` with the following signatures:

```
public <U> Optional<U> flatMap​(Function<? super T,​ ? extends Optional<? extends U>> mapper)
```

and

```
public Optional<T> or​(Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends T>> supplier)
```

`Optional` can never be extended, so what is the point of the parts like `? extends Optional<...>` in these signatures? Why not just `Optional<...>` ?

From answers to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970385/) here about the final `String` class I only understood that the compiler doesn't have to reject such constructs. I agree with that, considering the examples that were given. But my question is rather focused on API design, not on the compiler ability to predict all possible use cases. Why did some ever need to allow for the possibility of, for example, a `Supplier` that yields instances of some impossible class extending `Optional`?

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607274/java-thencomparing-wildcard-signature) for a similar situation in that the use of wildcards is rather pointless. It appears that this is a coding convention.

Comment: @Sweeper It is interesting to note that, in Java 8, `flatMap` had a slightly different signature (there was no `or` in Java 8). So if this is really a code convention, then the JDK team apparently changed it over time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class `Optional` is `final`, hence can not have subclasses, but it is generic, hence allows an infinite number of *parameterized types* having subtyping relationships on their own.

For example, the following code is only valid due to the signature you’ve shown in the question:

```java
Optional<Object> o = Optional.empty();
Supplier<Optional<String>> s = () -> Optional.of("str");
Optional<Object> combined = o.or(s);
```

An `Optional<String>` is not a subtype of `Optional<Object>`, so `Optional<? extends T>` is required in the signature, as an `Optional<String>` is a subtype of `Optional<? extends Object>`.

But a `Supplier<Subtype>` is not a subtype of `Supplier<Supertype>`, so we need `Supplier<? extends Supertype>` to allow a supplier of the subtype whereas `Optional<? extends T>` is the supertype here.

So `Supplier<Optional<String>>` is a subtype of `Supplier<? extends Optional<? extends Object>>`.