# Are there any use cases for using a final class, enum or record type as a type parameter bound?

Tags: java, generics

You can restrict type parameters with a bound in Java. For example:

```
interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
    // ...
}
```

You can use many kinds of types for the bound, including interfaces, classes, parameterized types and type parameters. In other words: `Bar` can be an interface, a class, etc. (it can't be a primitive or an array type).

You can also use `final` classes, `enum` and `record` types as bounds. So the above still works when `Bar` is a `final` class, `enum` or `record`.

But `enum` and `record` types are implicitly `final` - it's not possible to create a subtype of an `enum` or `record`. This implies that when you use an `enum` or `record` as a type parameter bound, then the only possibility to fill in the type parameter is with that specific `enum` or `record` type itself as the type argument. The same goes for `final` classes.

It makes no sense to have a `Foo<T>` if `T` cannot be anything other than `Bar` itself; in that case you could just as well leave out the type parameter from `Foo` entirely and directly use `Bar`.

Are there cases in which it makes sense that you can use a `final` class, `enum` or `record` type as a type parameter bound?

Comment: It is kinda difficult to answer the "why" part. It's a language design decision. You will probably have to ask the actual creators / wait for them to respond.

Comment: And you aren't the first to stumble about this. Angelika calls `<T extends String>` a nonsensical example in 2004 or so: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ002 ... because of exactly that reason: only String can be used, and there is point in doing it this way.

Comment: [Relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585). Not saying that this is *the* reason, but there are *way* better and more important features to spend time on, than disallowing you to use these types as type bounds.

Comment: @Sweeper I want to know if there are any particular use cases for this, which might provide a good reason why this is allowed - I am not asking for opinions. Also, this question is not "vague" as your link suggests. If there really is no good reason, then so be it, we can regard it as an oversight by the language designers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Generics wildcard extends final class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970385/java-generics-wildcard-extends-final-class)

Comment: @Joe Thanks, that question shows a potential use case.

Comment: I am voting to reopen. I suggest you edit the  title and body of your Question to focus on example use cases rather than the “why”.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there cases in which it makes sense that you can use a final class, enum or record type as a type parameter bound?

No.

See Angelika Langer's [FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ102) for example. There are no useful applications of such bounds.

---

<sub>Why is it allowed then?
Pass!</sub>

One potential explanation though: it keeps the language simpler. Additional constraints require additional checking, thus additional implementation cost.

Comment: I've seen the FAQ and agree, but maybe someone has a better reason to explain it than "it's allowed but not useful". If that's really the only explanation, then it seems to be an oversight by the language designers.

Comment: @Jesper I wouldn't really call it an oversight. There are a number of such "supported" but pointless features in the language. I *guess* their philosophy is "if it doesn't add room for confusion or bugs, let's not worry about it being useless; the time would be better spent elsewhere". It apparently wasn't even worth the time to introduce a warning.

Comment: @Jesper Why complicate the language with these types of rules, when you can also just allow it. It will not cause problems and allows for simplicity, and make code changes that make something non-final (or final) less painful, etc.