# Since String is a final class, how can a wildcard <? extends String> be correct?

Tags: java

In a course on Spring Batch, I was surprised to see `? extends String`.
Since String is a final class, how is this correct?

```
            public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(String.format("Received list of size: %s", items.size()));
                items.forEach(System.out::println);
            }
```

Comment: I think your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17970774/11230588

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that there will never be another class that extends `String`. So the only type that can fill that `?` is `String` itself. However, the `extends` / `super` still [conveys intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). Namely, a `List<? extends String>` is a read-only list. You can't add elements to it since `? extends String` is a producer. A `List<String>` is potentially a read-write collection. So by writing `List<? extends String>`, we're conveying to whoever is reading the code (and to the compiler) that we only intend to *read* values from this `List`, not write anything back.

Comment: A benefit following from that: When you have an unmodifiable `List<String>` (from wherever), the signature tells you that you can pass the unmodifiable list as an argument and won’t be hit by an `UnsupportedOperationException` because the method tried to put something into it. (Sure it technically could, but it’s really unlikely practically.)

Answer (score 3):

Technically you are correct, in this case only a `String` would work because `String` is final. Still best to always follow [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723538/2970947). A more practical example would probably use `? extends CharSequence`. For example,

```
public static void write(List<? extends CharSequence> items) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Received list of size: %s", items.size()));
    items.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Now you can call it with any kind of `CharSequence`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    write(List.of(new StringBuilder("Hello"), new StringBuilder("World")));
    write(List.of("Hello", "World"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`? extends String` is a generics qualifier. What it means in this particular case is that the method expects a `List` of elements which are compatible with `String`. There is nothing wrong with this definition - in fact, I would even consider it slightly more accurate and universal than `List<String>`.

But you're right, since there will never be another `String`, this is equivalent to `List<String>` for all practical purposes.